# How to fetch JSON field from JSON?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So far my code is -

```
async function fetchDatafromDB (client, IDs)
{
  let mapData =new Map ();
  for (var i=0; i<IDs.length; i++) {
    console.log ('the value is ' + IDs [i]);

    const cursor =client.db ('snapp_transactions').collection ('price_check_validation').find ({
      Scenario: {
        $in: [
          IDs[i]
        ]
      }

    });

    while (await cursor.hasNext ())
    {
      let ts = Date.now () ;
      // console .log ('the data');
      const obj = (JSON.stringify (await cursor.next ()));
      console.log ('The value obj' + obj) ;
      var obj1 = JSON.parse (obj) ;
      console.log (obj1['Execution Environment']) ;
    }
```

how can i fetch all the value from the JSON ?

sample of JSON is -

```
{"_id":"6114ce6514796e5fbe316be2","App":"PRO_WH_DS","Other Voucher Code":"","Date and Time Performed":"","SnApp Error":"","Done":"","Unit Tax Quoted":"$27.19","AQ perDayNetPrice":"","Gold "Upgrade Tax"":"","Gold Source":"","Execution Time":"2021-08-12T07:31:49.663Z","SnApp API Tax Inclusive (YN)":"","Voucher Bridging Amount (7800)":""}
```

with out entering the field manually .

Comment: First parse the JSON using `JSON.parse`. What values are you wanting? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Adding the complete code in my Question.

Comment: JSON refers to the stringified version of the object. What you really want is to (a) convert your JSON to a JS object, then (b) get all the values of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` to get all the values:

```js
console.log(Object.values({"_id":"6114ce6514796e5fbe316be2","App":"PRO_WH_DS","Other Voucher Code":"","Date and Time Performed":"","SnApp Error":"","Done":"","Unit Tax Quoted":"$27.19","AQ perDayNetPrice":"","Gold Upgrade Tax":"","Gold Source":"","Execution Time":"2021-08-12T07:31:49.663Z","SnApp API Tax Inclusive (YN)":"","Voucher Bridging Amount (7800)":""}))
```